# Do I need a "the" in the sentence: Tourists should be polite to (the) local people

Tags: articles

And please explain why.

I am always a bit confused about whether to add "the" or other articles in my sentence. And although I can find a lot of resources online, it honestly doesn't seem to help a lot as it all feels still like fuzzy.

Would you help me explain whether I should say

> Tourists should be polite to local people

or

> Tourists should be polite to the local people.

in a general context about how tourists should behave in their destinations.

Comment: In this case, I don't think it makes any difference whether you use the article or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for "the" before the plural noun "people".

You would use "the" when a particular group of local people had been identified from context.  For example, if you said "In the village tourists mingle with local people. Tourists should be polite to the local people".  It means "Those local people who mingle with tourists in the village."

Otherwise, as a piece of general advice, which group of local people is not determined and you don't use "the".